# Implementing multiple event listeners into a background class

Tags: java, android, events, listener

I have an activity that is already getting pretty bulky as far as the code goes (at least compared to how heavy the rest of the classes are) so I was hoping to create a simple helper class. I wanted to simply create a class (like SimpleSessionManager) that would implement location and sensor event listeners for me. Is there a way to do this utilizing a simple class via constructors, or is there a way to run the helper class as a background activity? From what I understand, I can not implement the event listeners through extending the Service class. Is this correct? Running it as a simple background activity would be ideal because then I could utilize the findViewById() method, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this with the Listeners responding as I had hoped. If the Fragment class would work, can someone point me in the direction of a related example as all that I can find I can't seem to get my implementation to work with.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of anonymous and inner classes?

Comment: In this case I feel as though an inner class wouldn't really accomplish the goal of keeping each individual class file condensed as well as allowing the code to be used throughout multiple classes (could be wrong). Haven't looked into anonymous. Any chance you have some documentation links on how it might relate to this? Thanks for the reply

Comment: Anonymous classes are ones where you don't specify a class name, you just inline it and assign to a variable. If you're wanting to declare handlers that can be used from a number of different classes, then just write each handler as its own top-level class implementing the appropriate interface. It might be helpful to put them in an "`event`" package.

Answer (score 0):

For utility classes I would go with a [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). For instance you could setup a LocationController that listens for location updates and any activity can just ask the singleton for the last location. Here is a small snippet of code to show you what I mean.

```
public class LocationController implements LocationListener {

    private static LocationController defaultController;

    public static LocationController getDefaultController(Context applicationContext) {
        if(defaultController == null) {
            defaultController = new LocationController();            

            LocationManager lm = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 30 * 1000, 1000, this);
        }

        return defaultController;
    }

    private Location lastLocation;

    private LocationController() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        lastLocation = location
    }

    public Location getLastLocation() {
        return lastLocation;
    }

}
```

Used in an Activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle SavedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);

    Location lastLocation = LocationController.getDefaultController(getApplicationContext()).getLastLocation();

}
```

I just used location as an example but singletons are really good for things you might want access to from multiple activities in your app. Because Android already gives you a pretty good location manager service I might not use this in your app but that's up to you. This pattern can be used for many types of listeners and data models. One thing to keep in mind is the use of the application context instead of the activity context. You don't want to use the activity context for things like this as it will cause you to leak the activity and eat up memory.

Another thing to be careful about with this pattern is remembering to turn off location updates. This will continue receiving location updates as long as Android has not removed your application from memory. That means that even though your app might not be active and thus not care about location updates it will still be requesting updates every 30 seconds. This is a very bad user experience as it will kill their battery very quickly.

Comment: I will definitely have to look into this. Thank you. Is the default controller method what pretty much makes it a singleton?

Comment: That and because there is only a single constructor that is private.

Comment: Gotcha, was looking at it on my phone earlier and was hard to see.